# How can I have 2 roles have the same routes in Laravel using middleware?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am new to Laravel and I am having trouble with Laravel's middleware. I have 2 roles Admin and Nurse, I want them to have common routes but it is not working.

Admin middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return response([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
                ], 401);
            }
        } else {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Unauthenticated'
            ], 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Nurse middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(Auth::user()->role == 'nurse'){
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return response([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
                ], 401);
            }
        } else {
            return response([
                'message' => 'Unauthenticated'
            ], 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

API routes:

```
// admin middleware
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','isAdmin'])->group(function(){
    // get all users
    Route::get('/search/{key?}', [UserController::class, 'search']);
    // level up user
    Route::put('/levelup/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    // delete user
    Route::delete('/users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'destroy']);
});

// nurse middleware
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','isNurse'])->group(function(){
    // users
    // get all users
    Route::get('/search/{key?}', [UserController::class, 'search']);
    // level up user
    Route::put('/levelup/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
});
```

I want the get all users and level up user routes to be common between both roles.

When I'm logged in as a nurse it is working properly but when I'm an admin it is not and I'm getting an error of unauthorized.

Comment: Do you need `return $next($request);` on the last line of both Admin and Nurse middleware?

Comment: @Adi No they are unnecessary I forgot to remove them

Answer (score 0):

you can use sanctum's standard [solution](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#token-abilities). Creating a token for each role and validating it in middleware

```php
$user->createToken('token-name', ['nurse'])->plainTextToken;
$user->createToken('token-name', ['admin'])->plainTextToken;

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    if (auth()->user()->tokenCan('nurse')) {
       return $next($request);
    }

    throw new \Exeption('Unauthorized', 401);
}
```

// second path

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','abilities:admin'])->group(function(){
    // get all users
    Route::get('/search/{key?}', [UserController::class, 'search']);
    // level up user
    Route::put('/levelup/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    // delete user
    Route::delete('/users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'destroy']);
});
```